# Describe a minimal injective resolution of $R$ as an $R$-module.

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $k$ be a field and $R=k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}$. Describe a minimal injective resolution of $R$ as an $R$-module (in terms of the Bass numbers of $R$).

**Solution:** Let $k$ be a field and $R=k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}$. Then
$$
k(p) = \left.R_p\middle/pR_p\right. = \left(\left.R\middle/pR\right.\right)_p = \mathrm{Quot}\left(\left.R\middle/pR\right.\right)
$$

Let $p\in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$. By assumption $R_p$ is Gorenstein, thus 
$$
\mathrm{Ext}_{R_p}^i\left(k(p),R_p\right)
= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ for } i\neq \dim R_p = \mathrm{ht}(p) \\
k(p) & \text{ if } i = \dim R_p = \mathrm{ht}(p).
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, $\mu_i(p,R)=\dim_{k(p)} \mathrm{Ext}_{R_p}^i \left(k(p),R_p\right) =\delta_{i,\mathrm{ht}(p)}$, which is the Bass number.

So I was trying to answer the question above and found the following answer. The problem though is that I am not sure that $R_p$ is Gorenstein. Can I get some help to show that (if it is indeed true)?

Comment: resolution? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm asking if your "$r$ solution" was supposed to be "resolution".

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry for the typo?

Comment: $R$ is a regular local ring, so it is Gorenstein.